# How to make an Object3D's face look at another face (eg. floor) by rotating the object

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, rotation, normals

## Sitation

A scene with a floor and an object that floats directly above it.

## What I am trying to do

When I click on a face of an object I want the whole object to rotate in such a way that the clicked face faces the floor.

## What I have tried so far

1. Click on any object's `face`: Raycaster picks up the first `face`.
2. replace the object's `up` vector with the `normal` of the clicked `face`: `object.up.copy(face.normal)`
3. call `object.lookAt(floor.position)`

I would expect that because of the new `up` vector, the object would lookAt the floor with an orientation based on the clicked face.

However, The rotation doesn't work as expected. What am I missing?

The relevant code part:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( cylinder );
    if(intersects === undefined || intersects.length === 0) return;


    let face = intersects[0].face;

    // Set cylinders up to the normal of the intersected face to reoriented object
    // to make the clicked-on face `lookAt()` the floor:
    cylinder.up.copy(face.normal);
    cylinder.up.normalize();
    cylinder.lookAt(floor.position);
```

#### The whole code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWRdZq

#### (UPDATE) The Fixed code

Based on @WestLangley's answer:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryZOvx

Comment: What you are missing is that `lookAt()` orients the object so that the object's local positive-z axis points in the desired direction. The object's up-vector keeps the object "right-side-up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to rotate an object so that a face's normal points in a particular direction.

In your example, the desired direction is in the direction of the negative-y axis, but you could specify any direction vector, as long as it has unit length.

You can use a pattern like so:

```
let direction = new THREE.Vector3( 0, - 1, 0 ); // create once and reuse

...

let object = intersects[ 0 ].object;
let normal = intersects[ 0 ].face.normal;

object.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( normal, direction );
```

Note that your problem statement does not have a unique solution. For example, the object can be "spun" on an axis and still have the face oriented in the desired direction.

three.js r.84

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing up the `up` usage. Also totally missed `setFromUnitVectors()` which apparently does exactly what I was trying to do! :)

Comment: Just for your info, the `quaternion` in line 1 above is never used later. The rest is valid.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. -